# Set time fron android terminal

Tags: android, linux, shell, time

I tried to set date from android script: I did: `su` 
`toybox date -d @[timestamp]`  but I got error " bad date format"
Help me please ( android version is 7.0)

Comment: You'll need to format your command as code to show the `<`, else the site thinks you're writing HTML tags. I'm not sure where you've put your su exactly - is it on the same line as the toybox? And can you give us an example timestamp please, i.e. exactly what you tried that gave you this error?

Comment: I got the error when i tried this script: `#!/system/bin/sh
toybox date -D @$(expr 1531055558 + `cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch`)`

Comment: I type on terminal : `su toybox date -d @1531193588` but the date didn't change! What I shall type (I type su then Enter...)